# Standard Triple Integral Problem

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

> Evaluate $ \iiint_D (x^2+y^2) \, ,\mathrm{d}V $, where $D$ is the
>   region bounded by the graphs of $y=x^2$, $z=4-y$, and $z=0$.

How would I do this problem? I can't even visualize the region D. I tried plotting it into Wolfram Alpha but it doesn't understand that I need to 3D plot it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To draw it, first try plotting the corresponding 2-dimensionl planes.

$y=x^2$ is just a parabola in the xy-plane. But notice z can be whatever it wants. This is how it looks in Wolfram: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=z+%3D+y-x^2 [**Please don't edit this again. It will not work as a hyperlink because of the ^ symbol in the URL.**]

Next, $z = 4-y$ is just a line in the yz-plane (plot z on the vertical axis in 2D). Then since there are no restrictions on x, it ends up being a flat plane in the xyz-plane that intersects the z-axis at z = 4, and intersects the y-axis at y = 4. [You can see it here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=z%28x%2Cy%29+%3D+4-y).

Finally, z=0 is equivalent to the xy-plane since there are no restrictions on either x nor y.

So now try to combine them all onto one graph.

With z on the vertical axis, you would get something similar to a half "cylinder" extending upwards ($y=x^2$) such that the peak of the parabola lies along the z-axis and extends into the positive y octant. This parabolic cylinder is bounded on the bottom by the xy-plane (ie. it has a flat bottom). Then it is bounded on the top by the plane $z=4-y$ which is at an angle. So your region ends up looking kind of like a rounded wedge.

Also, when you want to plot on Wolfram in 3D, you have to make sure it knows that you have three variables. For example, I wrote it as $z(x,y) = 4-y$. That way Wolfram knows you have three different coordinates, x,y,z.

Edit:

As for solving it, I would probably do it in the order dz dy dx. (If you integrate with respect to x *first* then the bounds on x would be $-\sqrt{y} \le x \le \sqrt{y}$. There's nothing wrong with doing it that way, I just prefer not to work with roots).

The bounds of z are given in the question.

The bounds on y can be found be recognizing that the parabola $y=x^2$ has its peak at the z-axis (y=0) and that it will be cut off by the plane $z = 4-y$ which intersects the y-axis at y=4.

The bounds on the x axis are a bit trickier. All you know about x is that $x^2 = y$. Then at y=0, x = 0, and at $y = 4, x = -2$ or $x = 2$. So x is bounded  by -2 and 2.

$0 \le z \le 4-y$

$x^2\le y \le 4$

$-2 \le x \le 2$

Answer (score 0):

The graph of $y = x^2$ doesn't depend on $z$, so it's an infinite sheet that is bent into the shape of a parabola.  The sheet before it's bent is perpendicular to the $xy$ plane.

The graph of $z = 4 - y$ doesn't depend on $x$ so it's a plane that crosses the $z$-axis at $z = 4$ and cuts the $xy$ plane at $y = 4$ in a line that's parallel to the $x$ axis.

The graph of $z = 0$ is simply the $xy$ plane.

So, the cross section in the region of the $xy$ plane ($z = 0$) is the inside of the parabola between $x = -2$ and $x = 2$, and extends from $y = 0$ to $y = 4$.  At $z = 2$ it's cut off at $y = 2$, which corresponds to $x = \sqrt{2}.$  The integration region vanishes at $z = 4$.

The bounds of integration for $x$ are $-\sqrt{y}$ to $\sqrt{y}$.  The bounds of integration for $y$ are $0$ to $4-z$.  The bound of integration for $z$ are $0$ to $4$.

Answer (score 0):

To start, it might make the problem easier to convert to cylindrical coordinates and then attempt to visualize the region. From that, you just switch your limits of integration accordingly and just integrate like normal (but don't forget about the Jacobian!).